# Apple Automator process csv files and create new files

Tags: python, macos, automator

Is it possible to loop through a set of selected files, process each, and save the output as new files using Apple Automator?

I have a collection of .xls files, and I've gotten Automator to

```
- Ask for Finder Items
- Open Finder Items
- Convert Format of Excel Files #save each .xls file to a .csv
```

I've written a python script that accepts a filename as an argument, processes it, and saves it as p_filename in the directory the script's being run from. I'm trying to use `Run Shell Script` with the `/usr/bin/python` shell and my python script pasted in.

Some things don't translate too well, though, especially since I'm not sure how it deals with python's `open('filename','w')` command. It probably doesn't have permissions to create new files, or I'm entering the command incorrectly. I had the idea to instead output the processed file as text, capture it with Automator, and then save it to a new file.

To do so, I tried to use `New Text File`, but I can't get it to create a new text file for each file selected back in the beginning. Is it possible to loop through all the selected Finder Items?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want this done in the folder of the script?  Or do you mean the folder of the files you are getting from the Finder items?  In that case just get the path for each file passed into Python.

When you run open('filename','w') you should thus pass in a full pathname.  Probably what's happening is you are actually writing to the root directory rather than where you think you are.

Assuming you are passing your files to the shell command in Automator as arguments then you might have the following:

```
import sys, os

args = sys.argv[1:]
for a in args:
    p = os.path.dirname(a)
    mypath = p + "/" + name
    f = open(mypath, "w")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to construct the path using os.path.join ?